# Get all values from one key in array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, image-upload

I want to get all the "file_name" values into one variable to be able to save it as a comma separated string into my database.

```
    array (size=13)
  0 => 
    array (size=14)
      'file_name' => string '__0000132.jpg' (length=13)
      'file_type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'file_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/mou/uploads/items/' (length=30)
      'full_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/mou/uploads/items/__0000132.jpg' (length=43)
      'raw_name' => string '__0000132' (length=9)
      'orig_name' => string '__00001.jpg' (length=11)
      'client_name' => string '__00001.jpg' (length=11)
      'file_ext' => string '.jpg' (length=4)
      'file_size' => float 2.16
      'is_image' => boolean true
      'image_width' => int 300
      'image_height' => int 300
      'image_type' => string 'jpeg' (length=4)
      'image_size_str' => string 'width="300" height="300"' (length=24)
  1 => 
    array (size=14)
      'file_name' => string '0132.jpg' (length=8)
      'file_type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'file_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/mou/uploads/items/' (length=30)
      'full_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/mou/uploads/items/0132.jpg' (length=38)
      'raw_name' => string '0132' (length=4)
      'orig_name' => string '01.jpg' (length=6)
      'client_name' => string '01.jpg' (length=6)
      'file_ext' => string '.jpg' (length=4)
      'file_size' => float 271.2
      'is_image' => boolean true
      'image_width' => int 580
      'image_height' => int 714
      'image_type' => string 'jpeg' (length=4)
      'image_size_str' => string 'width="580" height="714"' (length=24)
  2 => 
    array (size=14)
      'file_name' => string 'CM_logo32.png' (length=13)
      'file_type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'file_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/mou/uploads/items/' (length=30)
      'full_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/mou/uploads/items/CM_logo32.png' (length=43)
      'raw_name' => string 'CM_logo32' (length=9)
      'orig_name' => string 'CM_logo.png' (length=11)
      'client_name' => string 'CM_logo.png' (length=11)
      'file_ext' => string '.png' (length=4)
      'file_size' => float 24.61
      'is_image' => boolean true
      'image_width' => int 393
      'image_height' => int 404
      'image_type' => string 'png' (length=3)
      'image_size_str' => string 'width="393" height="404"' (length=24)
  3 => 
    array (size=14)
      'file_name' => string 'download32.png' (length=14)
      'file_type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'file_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/mou/uploads/items/' (length=30)
      'full_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/mou/uploads/items/download32.png' (length=44)
      'raw_name' => string 'download32' (length=10)
      'orig_name' => string 'download.png' (length=12)
      'client_name' => string 'download.png' (length=12)
      'file_ext' => string '.png' (length=4)
      'file_size' => float 33.18
      'is_image' => boolean true
      'image_width' => int 160
      'image_height' => int 120
      'image_type' => string 'png' (length=3)
      'image_size_str' => string 'width="160" height="120"' (length=24)
```

Im using codeigniter and this is what my library returns  from $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data(); Library ->> https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

Any help will be much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP >= 5.5 you can use [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$results = array_column($myArray, 'file_name');
```

For earlier versions of PHP, you can use

```
$results = array_map(
    function ($value) {
        return $value['file_name'];
    }
    $myArray
);
```

But saving as a comma-separated string in your database is not a good recommendation: it makes it practically unsearchable (you can't use indexes for searching, so it's a full scan) and it becomes very difficult to modify as well

Comment: How can I set a key to each with array_map?

Comment: You can't set a key, PHP will use the key from the original array. Why do you need to set a key?

Comment: im getting this with json_encode ["DSC_348410.jpg","IMAGE_NAME11.jpg","dry-cleaning11.png","tube_map11.gif","0110.jpg","fb_header10.jpg","dslr.center_logo_10.png"] but want it back as a php array

Comment: What exactly do you want? Please edit your original question to show ___exactly___ what you want the PHP array to look like after getting the list of file names..... this is the first time you've even mentioned json, so it feels as though what you're asking for has changed

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it was.

Basically missing a comma.

```
 $fileData =$this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
    $results = array_map(
        function ($fileData) {
            return $fileData['file_name'];
        },
        $fileData
    );
```

returns an array of file names from the Codeigniter Library  https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload